# How to taking snapshot using softassertion in java

Tags: java, selenium, testng

i am software automation engineer, i am working on the product. for some days i am facing a problem regarding to soft assertion and hard assertion.

1) in my scenario i need to close the tab, before closing the tab if tase case is failed I need to take the snapshot of failed screen, when i am using hard assertion, system takes the snapshot but close the tab and take the snapshot of other screen so this is not a good technique , when i am using soft assertion then the system does not take the snapshot. any can help me the best solution for this

```
if (IspersistTotalTickets == false) {
                CloseTab();
                Assert.assertTrue(IspersistTotalTickets == false);
                logger.log(LogStatus.PASS,"Test case Pass:Tickets are Not showing On the Registeration Site");

            } else {
                SoftAssert softAssert = new SoftAssert();
                softAssert.assertTrue(IspersistTotalTickets == false);
                softAssert.assertAll();
                //ITestResult result1=FAILURE;
                //this.testIT(result1);
                CloseTab();
                logger.log(LogStatus.FAIL, "Test case Failed:Total Tickets are Found On the Registeration Site");
            }

@AfterMethod
    public void testIT(ITestResult result) throws Exception {
        if (ITestResult.FAILURE == result.getStatus()) {
            String screenShotPath = utility.captureScreenshot(driver, result.getName());
            // System.out.println("screenshot path:"+screenShotPath);
            String image = logger.addScreenCapture(screenShotPath);
            logger.log(LogStatus.FAIL, result.getName(), image);
        }

        report.endTest(logger);
        report.flush();
        // driver.quit();
    }
```

i need correct snapshot before closing the tab

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code, the easiest thing to do would be to just always take the screenshot before the hard assertion (and if you don't want it persisted when there's no failure, than delete the screenshot after the assert passes), or take the screenshot before the assertAll() in the soft assert.

However, I would recommend instead to look at restructuring the tests to move what seems like cleanup (closeTab()) to @AfterTest, and creating a rule (@Rule) which will take a screenshot whenever a test fails by overriding TestWatcher.failed().

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, First of all system takes the snapshot in the case when any test case failed i am using this functionality in the After the method ,  how i can call the after method forcefully?

Comment: when i close the tab before the assert then how i can get the snapshot of latest screen ?